# setState increases the like counts for all instances. How can I increase like count for each individual record in class component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a code that works the way I want except when the button calling the "handleLike" handler, it increases the like count on all records instead of one. I have created a local state in the class to test this and here is my code snippet. I would like to use this class component to enable this feature of increasing the like counting functionality for each record. Any advice will be appreciated.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {deleteProduct} from '../actions/deleteProduct'


class ProductsShow extends React.Component {

    state = {
       like: 0  
    }
    
    render(){
       
        const handleDelete = (product) => {
            this.props.deleteProduct(product.id, product.vendor_id)
        }

        const handleLike = (like) => {
            this.setState({
                like: like + 1
                
            })
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.products && this.props.products.map(product => 
                    <div className="product_info" key={product.id} id={product.id}>
                         <h3 id="prod_name_header">{product.name}</h3>
                         <li>Description: {product.description}</li>
                         <li> price: ${product.price}</li>
                         <li key={product.kind}> Kind: {product.kind}</li>
                         <li key={product.discount_rate}> discount-rate: {product.discount_rate}</li><br></br>
                         <button onClick={()=> handleDelete(product)}>Delete</button>
                         <button onClick={()=> handleLike(this.state.like)}>{this.state.like}</button>
                    </div>
                   
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}

export default connect(null, {deleteProduct})(ProductsShow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a seperate `Product` component that has individual `like` state in it so that each of the item in the product has its own like property.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { deleteProduct } from "../actions/deleteProduct";

class ProductsShow extends React.Component {
  handleDelete = product => {
    this.props.deleteProduct(product.id, product.vendor_id);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.products &&
          this.props.products.map(product => (
            <Product
              product={product}
              onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(product)}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Product extends React.Component {
  state = {
    like: 0
  };

  handleLike = () => {
    this.setState({
      like: this.state.like + 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { product, onDelete } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="product_info" key={product.id} id={product.id}>
        <h3 id="prod_name_header">{product.name}</h3>
        <li>Description: {product.description}</li>
        <li> price: ${product.price}</li>
        <li key={product.kind}> Kind: {product.kind}</li>
        <li key={product.discount_rate}>
          {" "}
          discount-rate: {product.discount_rate}
        </li>
        <br />
        <button onClick={onDelete}>Delete</button>
        <button onClick={handleLike}>{this.state.like}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```